# formula for conditional formatting in excel

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

[So what I want is to show in red everything that is missing and is older than 2 hours, but with my current formula showing in red, all that is missing. see the picture please [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSnAN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyahm.png)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the IF, TRUE or FALSE:-
[image: Screenshot illustrating suggested conditional-formatting formula]